# Facebook scope permission - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using Facebook Scope video_upload and photo_upload to upload video and photo for my iOS app users.

```
FBSession* sess = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"basic_info", @"publish_actions", @"photo_upload",@"publish_stream",@"video_upload", nil]];
```

But I just found that, using the latest Facebook iOS SDK 3.15, I may need to submit for approval?

[image]

I see this in my developer panel.

[image]

Question: 
Pressing "Start a Submission", I could find publish_actions, but not video_upload. Can I upload video on behave of users after approval of publish_actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the Facebook docs, then you'd find your answer:

- Videos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos#publish
- Photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#publish

You need the `publish_actions` for both.

Remember that you should only start the submission if your app is ready for Facebook to test it. If it's not, you can always use the admin or the test users to test the functionalities while developing.

Comment: Thanks, Tobi. +1 for the tips of approval submission.

Answer (score 1):

now `basic_info` is deprecated in ver 2.0 in `Facebook permission`, just remove the `basic_info` and build your application, need reference use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

Comment: publish_actions is the required permission for video and photo upload. But thanks for reminding me on removing basic_info, +1 for the tips.